# File doesn't gets writen with data despite it being the same as the other that does work

Tags: c, file

I'm working on a project for a class. It should fill an array with random numbers from 0 to maxNum, remember the biggest, get an avarage and then copy the data on 2 binary files.  Here's the relevant part:

```
FILE *pf, *rf;
int numCant = 50, maxNum = 100;
int n, i, avg = 0, m = 0;
pf = fopen("file.dat", "wb+");
rf = fopen("backupFile.dat", "wb+");
srand( floor(time( NULL )));

for (i = 0; i < numCant; i++) {
    n = rand() % maxNum;
    avg += n;
    if (m < n)
        m = n;
    fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, pf);
    fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, rf);
}
```

This works perfectly for the first file (fp) but for some reason the second file (rf) wont save anything. The file will be created but remain empty. Can someone explain to me the diference between `pf` and `rf` so that only one works?

Comment: This code Looks Fine. Check the close statements: are both files getting closed at the end?

Comment: Are both files writable?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `fflush()` after each `fwrite()`, like this

```
fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, pf);
fflush(pf);

fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), 1, rf);
fflush(rf);
```

also, remember to `fclose()` each file when you finish, and check that `fopen()` didn't return `NULL`, it's not guaranteed that openning a file for writing will succeed.

Comment: In theory, neither the `fflush()` nor the `fclose()` should matter if the program exits normally; the system should flush any pending output and close the file streams automatically.  It is still a good idea to close the files; that which you open you should close.  Checking `fopen()` is necessary.  It is a little unlikely that the code would not crash if the `fopen()` calls fail, but maybe this system allows the code to survive.  Or maybe the trouble is that it fails on the second file, but the problem hasn't been noticed.

Comment: Unnecessary flushes reduce the performance gain achieved by output buffering. The main rule here is: one should always close the file after use. Then the automatic flush is done during closing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the files after the write operation.

```
fclose (pf);
fclose(rf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently OSX Finder handles files strangely, the file showed as "Zero bytes" when viewed on Finder (File explorer), but the data was inside when I opened the file with a text editor. Should I delete the question since the code was not my problem after all?

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your answer a bit and then accept your own answer.  Did you have the file open in an editor at the same time that your program was running?